# Acer Aspire One 725 unstable WiFi connection

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, wireless, aspire-one

I installed 12.10 on an Acer Aspire One 725. There were intermittent problems with the WiFi disconnecting and connecting again and again.

I thought this might be an issue with 12.10. So I installed 12.04. I'm getting the same problems with 12.04 too. Which probably points a finger at the hardware or drivers for the Aspire One 725. I have six other devices that are working perfectly with the same WiFi router.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, I found that it was the broadcom chipset, it even fighting with the the other 'atheros' chipsets in my family to the point where there internet became unusable.

I just replace the chipset in my Acer 725 with an atheros one and all is well now.